# Boolean gate logic

Tags: boolean-logic

I've got this expression and I believe I have the circuit drawn out correctly however I think the truth table for it is a trick question. There is 4 inputs and 2 of them are A and the other 2 are B and C. Here is what I've drawn out:

[image]

Here's what I've done for the truth table.

[image]

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: How is the truth table drawn out m8?

Comment: Compute `A AND B`, then `A AND C`, then the `NOR` of the two (each in separate columns). Each step should be fairly trivial.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. Seems like more of a general [cs.se] problem (although they may not be particularly welcoming to this particular question).

Comment: Either your inputs are labeled wrong or your schematic is drawn wrong. The schematic for the expression would have the "A's" on both AND gates shorted together, which would give you 3 distinct inputs. You can check your truth table using http://mustpax.github.io/Truth-Table-Generator/

Comment: See also http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/logisim/ which can be used to construct simple digital circuits and simulate their operation. You can take screenshots of your circuits for extra win. :D The program is free.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your logic expression can be simplified using Boolean Algebra.**

Start with the given logic expression:

```
(ab + ac)'
```

Factor out `a`:

```
(a(b + c))'
```

Apply De Morgan's law for negation of a conjunction:

```
a' + (b + c)'
```

Apply De Morgan's law for negation of a disjunction:

```
a' + b'c'
```

Therefore, output is true:

- anytime `a` is false, OR
- when `b` is false AND `c` is false

**Here is your truth table with corrections:**
[image]

Comment: Ok I've taken advice and broken it into smaller chunks. http://gyazo.com/229efc4e4c8908546e19958a6205c417

Answer (score 0):

A false, output true (regardless of B and C)
B and C false, output true (regardless of A)
Your truth table is not correct.

Comment: Can you draw it out please?